# How to mix left-align with bold/italics/underline in GraphViz/dot/xdot

Tags: layout, alignment, graphviz, dot

I'd like to do UML class diagrams with GraphViz and dot/xdot.

There are 2 main layout options which can be mixed, but not in a single element (line).

- I would like to make the names of classes and interfaces **bold**.
- Interfaces and abstract classes should have names in *Italics*.
- Static methods/attributes should be underlined.

That's doable with the subset of html, which is supported by GraphViz.

- I would like to align all attributes and all methods to the left, which is easy to do with the GraphViz internal syntax: append a `\l` to the entry.

But I didn't find a way to mix these features into a single record element. Source:

```
digraph UMLleftItalics {
    graph [ rankdir=BT ]
    node [ shape=record ]
    Joinable [label=<{&laquo;interface&raquo;<br/><b><i>\N</i></b>| + joinTo (other : &lt;T&gt;) : void<br />+ unjoinFrom (other : &lt;T&gt;) : void<br />| <u>- fooStatic () : void </u>}> ]
    FooJoiner [label="{\N|  - name : String\l- dateOfBirth : Date\l- id : int\l- counter : int (static) \l| + joinTo (FooJoiner) : void\l+ unjoinFrom (FooJoiner) : void\l}"]

    FooJoiner -> Joinable [style=dashed arrowhead=empty]
}
```

Image:
[image: UML Diagram from GraphViz/dot]

As you can see, Joinable in reduced HTML-code is bold and italics, but the attributes/methods aren't left aligned, but the static method (which is semantically false in an interface, but a) for brevity and b) who says it's Java :) ) is underlined.

FooJoiner in GraphViz internal language isn't bold but should. But it is left aligned in members and methods. No underline and italics either.

Answer (score 2):

Using an HTML table:

```
digraph UMLleftItalics {
    graph [ rankdir=BT ]
    node [ shape=none ]
    
   Joinable [label=<<table>
    <tr><td>&laquo;interface&raquo;<BR/><b><i>\N</i></b></td></tr>
    <tr><td align="left">+ joinTo (other : &lt;T&gt;) : void <br align="left"/>+ unjoinFrom (other : &lt;T&gt;) : void</td></tr>
    <tr><td align="left"> <u>- fooStatic () : void </u></td></tr>
    </table>> ]
 

    FooJoiner [label=<<table>
    <tr><td><b><i>\N</i></b></td></tr>
    <tr><td align="left">- name : String<br align="left"/>- dateOfBirth : Date id : int<br align="left"/>- id : int<br align="left"/>- counter : int (static)<br align="left"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td align="left">+ joinTo (FooJoiner) : void<br align="left"/>+ unjoinFrom (FooJoiner) : void</td></tr>
    </table>> ]

    FooJoiner -> Joinable [style=dashed arrowhead=empty]
}
```

Giving:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's an idea. Is it possible to get rid of the double line frame and have simple lines?

Comment: Yep, use this: ```<table BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0">```